# Terminal automatically closed while installing openstack on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install openstack on ubuntu 14.04 LTS in VMware player. I have done this installation in fresh ubuntu 14.04 version. After adding this command ./stack.sh it asked for some passwords and after that it continues installing. But later all of a sudden the terminal closes and log out the user. When i log in terminal session was gone and in /opt/stack directory some projects were there. I am unable to find stack.sh.log file to see if there is any error. Any help ?